# SQL pull a value that exsists on the INNER JOIN column of the query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to store a value from the column that inner joins two tables. Not sure if my logic is correct. As of now in a drop down list when an `option` is selected the **`value`** is stored into a session variable which returns **NULL**. Here is my query with result print out:

```
$query = 
"
SELECT c.emp_id
     , c.client_contact_id
     , c.project_id
     , p.project_id
     , p.project_codename
  FROM tlive_project_clist c
  JOIN tlive_project p 
    ON p.project_id = c.project_id 
 ORDER 
    BY p.project_codename
 ";

echo <select name="Projects">;

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die("Query error: " . mysqli_error($con));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){  
  echo '<option value="'.$row['project_id'].'">'.$row['project_codename'].'</option>';
}

echo </select>;
```

php validation:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('php/config.php');

$project_id = $_POST['Projects'];

if(empty($project_id)){
  echo '*Please select a project';
}
else{               
$_SESSION['PROJECT_ID'] = $project_id;  
}
?>
```

Comment: Why are you outputting both `c.project_id` and `p.project_id` if they are always going to be the same value?

Comment: I was confused about what he was storing, but it sounds like he meant using the values retrieved as the value for the 'value' attribute in the option tag.  Hence why he states 'As of now when one option is selected the value is stored as NULL.'  However, further clarification would be helpful.

Comment: What does your data look like? Please share information about your table structure/data with an sqlfiddle please. http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Also you need to look at a `var_dump($row)` and see the key names you have there.  You aren't using aliases for your field names, so I don't think the array keys in `$row` match what you expect.

Comment: Here is a sqlfiddle example: [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36cc5/2)

Comment: I just want to store one value from the the project_id column into a session variable @SlyRaskal